# How to get Connection Pool from EclipseLink

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, eclipselink, connection-pooling

hello i have a JPA (EclipseLink) App already working and another application with pure JDBC deployed onto the same server and pointing into the same DB and schema so want to make the JDBC app to be able to get the Connection Pool from EclipeLink in order to centralize the pool conn..if someone knows or have any idea how to do this please let me know. Thanks in advance.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see 
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/EMAPI#Getting_a_JDBC_Connection_from_an_EntityManager
for examples on setting this up in JPA 1.0 or in JPA 2.0.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but as of Jul2019, using eclipselink 2.5.0 and querydsl 4.2.1, the proposed unwrap(Connection.class) approach returns null in my own project. Solved it by creating the needed JPASQLQuery and passing the existing entityManager as parameter (see http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.2.1/apidocs/com/querydsl/jpa/sql/JPASQLQuery.html)